# Unable to get Wireless ADB working - removing USB cable will disconnect the TCPIP device

Tags: android, adb, wireless

Device: HTC One

Requirements: get Wireless ADB working so i can play around with USB OTG, with peripheral connected.

Network topology: Mobile device has wireless hotspot enabled, development machine is connected to this hotspot.

Notes: Device is rooted, Wifi ADB is installed

when i run Wifi ADB it gives me two IP addresses
192.168.1.1/24
10.114.254.41/30
Port:8000

With all the guides i've followed, i've managed to connect to 192.168.1.1
i've ran adb -s 192.168.1.1 logcat and that spews out a lot of data; a good sign.

the command 'adb devices' shows the usb device and the IP device
however, if i unplug the usb cable i lose connection...
running the command 'adb devices' now shows no devices..

Any ideas? too frustrated to think straight atm, its ridiculous how complicated this is, i just want to write some frigging code -_-

Comment: calling the methods: 'adb tcpip 8000', 'adb shell' do not return; the methods seem to hang and i cannot type additional commands into the cmd prompt; maybe this is related.

Answer (score 9):

The following works fine for me:

1. Connect the device via the cable
2. Run `adb tcpip <port>` where `<port>` is the port on which your device will listen
3. Disconnect the cable and connect your peripheral
4. Run `adb connect <device ip>:<port>`

After this you should be able to debug your apps as over a wired connection.

Comment: yea i think my problem is surrounding the adb tcpip 8000 command that I’m administering, 
when I run the command from the PC I get the feedback: “restarting in TCP mode port: 8000”,
but the method call does not exit, the command window does not appear to progress.

Comment: My issue was running adb connect while still plugged in to the computer. After unplugging, running adb connect stuck

Comment: I was facing the same issue but this works great with Nexus5X, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

rebooting the phone seems to have fixed it :/

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting definitely did not fix it here. I can establish a WiFi TCP/IP connection to ADB, it works great and debugging proceeds normally. But if I'm debugging a USB peripheral, and I disconnect the USB cable, I lose the ADB connection. I have to "adb connect", then go into DDMS and manually reassociate with the still-running app. Extremely annoying!

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted then it is very simple to make a wireless connection. I used this app from Google Play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) and it worked perfect, just try.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to stay connected. That's why I wrote this adb auto reconnect shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "i need one parameter: the address (with port) of your android phone"
    exit 1
fi

while true; do
    if [ $(adb devices | grep "$1" | wc -l) -lt 1 ]; then
        adb connect $1
        adbExitCode=$?
        if [ $adbExitCode -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "adb connect failed"
        fi
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Source: https://github.com/StareInTheAir/shell-scripts/blob/master/adb-auto-reconnect

Not elegant, but it works.